# Magento 2 Staging url gets redirected to production

Tags: magento2, staging, production

I had setup staging environment for my magento 2.3 site.
The setup is same like production.
When i click on anything on staging site, it gets redirected to production.
Checked everything(base url , config data) everything is correct.
Cleared cache also.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: have you check base_url in core_config_data ?

Comment: search for live url in core_config_data table, check and change the URL that is pointing to live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please find production url on your folder may be add production url
>   static anywhere in file or .htaccess file.